# uninstall and install Visual Studio Professional2013

Tags: visual-studio

I have something wrong in Visual Studio Professional 2013.

So,I want to uninstall and then reinstall it.

After I uninstall and run the exe, I got the error message.

```
Visual Studio Professional 2013 is currently installed on the machine. 
Please uninstall Visual Studio Professional 2013 and retry.
```

Is there something I should delete ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Visual Studio Uninstaller:
https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller

Speaking from experience, it might help, or it might hopelessly break the installation and require you to reinstall Windows to get everything working again.

Comment: OH, THanks .
But,That's too late..
I have the new OS installed computer.